# SFTP on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server, sftp

For a requirement of one of our partners, I need to offer an SFTP service to host a file that will change daily. The requirement for the use of SFTP is decided and beyond my control.

I want to offer this service on the same machine where the hosted file is created. This is a Windows Server 2012 R2 server.

Since this machine contains sensitive data, I want to choose a server where the creator(s) can be trusted. And of course, if possible, for free or little cost.

I have considered installing OpenSSH on the machine, but I don't really want to expose the entire OS from SSH and have it be linked to the Windows Users (etc), just to host one file via SFTP. (Btw, this is an assumption I am making.)

Answer (score 1):

You could setup a secure FTPS server using IIS on Windows Server 2012.

https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_ftps_server#on_windows_server_2016_and_windows_server_2012

As you can see on this response https://serverfault.com/questions/648855/is-iis-sftp-natively-supported-by-windows-server-2012-r2 SFTP is not supported by default on Windows Server OS, you will have to install SSH.